# Can Malt extract or Wort be inverted?

Tags: extract, malt

You can invert Sucrose sugar (UK table sugar) into Fructose and Glucose, by heating with citric acid, (FYI This is how you make belgian candy sugar guys!).

I'm not too hot on my Malt, but there is a cocktail of sugars in there including Maltose after mashing.

Can this (Malt/Malt Extract/Wort) be inverted? bonus question is there any use for this, how does it relate to beer?

I feel this may be a disappointingly quick answer.

Comment: If you;re referring to the rock candi sugar, no, that's not how it's made.  Invert sugar remains a liquid.

Comment: I thought you just bring to a hard-crack after inverting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it can be done.  No, there's no point to it.  Some say that invert sugars are easier for the yeast to ferment, but the yeast will invert any sugars in the wort.  Inverting the sugar first really makes no difference to the fermentation.  Depending on how you do the inversion, you may or may not get Maillard reaction products that may affect the flavor.

Comment: That's right, the yeast secrete invertase to break down succrose.

Comment: I accept there is no point with Wort. Otherwise I think the maillard reaction is usually the primary reason for inverting, such as with some Belgian beers, correct?

Comment: Isn't the pro-inverting argument that yeast can skip the invertase process? The downside is due to the maillard reaction more sugar is required for the same fermentability.

Comment: That's the argument, but the reality is that it doesn't matter.